# Attaining a list of Styles of a specific TargetType

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I want to attain a list of styles that apply to a specific control type. I'd like to do something like the code below, but not have to specify a key name and get a list of applicable resources back. Is this possible?

```
ComponentResourceKey key = new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(MyControlType), ""); 
Style style = (Style)Application.Current.TryFindResource(key);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it make sense to first examine the `Resources` of your control, and then continue walking up the `VisualTree` examining `Resources` along the way to simulate how WPF finds resources for your control (including `Styles`)?

For example, maybe you could create an extension method that does this given a `FrameworkElement`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public static class FrameworkElementHelper
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Style> FindStylesOfType<TStyle>(this FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
        {
            IEnumerable<Style> styles = new List<Style>();

            var node = frameworkElement;

            while (node != null)
            {
                styles = styles.Concat(node.Resources.Values.OfType<Style>().Where(i => i.TargetType == typeof(TStyle)));
                node = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(node) as FrameworkElement;
            }

            return styles;
        }
    }
}
```

To see that this works, create XAML file that has both implicit and explicit `Styles` at multiple levels in the `VisualTree`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" />
        <Style x:Key="NamedButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" />
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" />
        <Style x:Key="NamedTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="No results yet." />
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Content="Find Styles" Click="OnMyButtonClick">
            <Button.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" />
                <Style x:Key="NamedButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" />
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" />
                <Style x:Key="NamedTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" />
            </Button.Resources>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and with the following handler in the code behind:

```
private void OnMyButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var styles = myButton.FindStylesOfType<Button>();
   myTextBlock.Text = String.Format("Found {0} styles", styles.Count());
}
```

In this example, 4 styles are found for the `myButton` all of which have a `TargetType` of `Button`. I hope this can be a good starting point. Cheers!

Comment: Good solution, but be aware that it won't always work. As you're using the Visual Tree, resources from TabItem for instance won't be found.